# Sankey diagram out of figure

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, sankey-diagram

So I'm creating, as the title says, a sankey with the help of plotly in python. The code can be seen here:

```
node = dict(label=ecu, pad=20)
link = dict(source=list(index_send), target=list(index_rec), arrowlen=15, value=combination_bps, color=sig_color)
layout = dict(width=1080, height=720)
data = go.Sankey(node=node, link=link)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

fig.show()
```

All the nodes and links are done perfectly, but when i show the figure it is not at all centered in the figure. Instead it is cutoff at the top (see picture).[Sankey diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IswQ4.png) Has anyone an idea what the problem could be?

I already tried it with margin_b, margin_t in the layout dict but it just squeezes the diagram.